# Berry phase with density matrix approach

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, berry-pancharatnam-phase

[Berry phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase#Berry_phase_in_quantum_mechanics), coming from Schrodinger equation, has well known form in terms of closed integral

$$\gamma = \int_C A(\xi) d\xi $$

with Berry connection $$A(\xi) = i < \psi(\xi) | \partial_{\xi} | \psi(\xi) > $$ and $\psi(\xi)$ is eigenstate of Schrodinger equation $$H |\psi> = E |\psi>.$$

Suppose instead you have system described by mixed state.

Is there generalization of Berry phase for density matrix $\rho$?

Comment: I'm not exactly certain what you mean here - the Berry phase may be defined in terms of pure states, but in the end, it's just a function on paths in $\xi$-parameter space. What do you mean by a "Berry phase for a density matrix"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind How to define Berry phase for mixed state?

Comment: The Berry phase is a function of a *path in parameter space*, not of a state (pure *or* mixed). I don't understand what you mean by a "Berry phase for mixed state". Can you give an example of a situation where you would need such a quantity?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Berry phase definiton in question comes from Schroedinger equation of pure state.  In open quantum system suppose you have density matrix for mixed state. How to compute Berry phase for such mixed state?

Comment: Do we have some sort of language problem here? The Berry phase is *defined* in terms of pure states, but it is a *function of a path*. It's not "for a pure state" or "for a mixed state", it's just a path in parameter space. What is the problem you are trying to solve when you want to "compute Berry phase for such mixed state"?

Comment: I am sorry that I don't have the time to provide you just now with a full answer.  But Berry phases exist also for mixed states (described by density matrices).  There is a vast amount of literature on the subject. 
Please, see the introduction to the following Viennot's article for many good references on the subject.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.7340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the notion of a berry phase makes sense for a general mixed state. This is because in general geometric phases in general are got by varying parameters in the Hamiltonian. This makes them inherently a geometric feature of $\textit{coherent}$ evolution.

Another way of seeing, is to consider the following particular situation: suppose you have one qubit in state $\psi(t=0) $ with Hamiltonian $H$. Then you change parameters in the $H$ so that the evolution of qubit is supposed to return to the original state $ \lambda \psi(t=0)$ where $\lambda$ is some $U(1)$ phase factor.Throughout the evolution we are staying on the surface of the Bloch sphere. Now if you want to bring in the possibility of mixed states then one way is to introduce noise in the evolution but as you change the parameters in the Hamiltonian the Bloch sphere is being deformed and in general your state may end up inside the Bloch sphere. In other words the possibility of returning to your state modulo global phases is in not possible for arbitrary mixed states.